# I don't really understand Page.FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have an image like this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="btnabout1" ImageUrl="~/graphics/buttons/btnabout1.png" AlternateText="About" />
```

I can access the control from code-behind like this (obviously):

```
btnabout1.Visible = false;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Page.FindControl("btnabout1").Visible = false;
```

The point is to use a variable controlID and set attributes.

I guess I am mis-understanding the method, so can someone enlighten me, please.

---

The purpose is to create a method that takes the filename of the current page and sets images/buttons visible/invisible accordingly.  Like this:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath);
string strippedfilename = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf("."));
Page.FindControl("btn" + strippedfilename + "3").Visible = true;
Page.FindControl("btn" + strippedfilename + "2").Visible = false;
Page.FindControl("btn" + strippedfilename + "1").Visible = false;
```

Since I could't get Page.FindControl to work, I am using a

```
Dictionary<string, Control[]>
```

instead, but of course it's not as dynamic because adding new pages would mean having to add to the dictionary, but I guess it's ok for now...

Comment: In which page lifecycle event you are calling `Page.FindControl()` method? Make sure it's at least `Page_Init` (or later event). You can take a look at this link to see recursive mathod for finding control by its ID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx. Also make sure the control is **NOT** inside an item template i.e. in `Repeater` control (it won't be found this way then).

Comment: Is this image in the yourpagename.aspx or in yourusercontrol.ascx?

Answer (score 0):

The overload you are using for [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) only looks at immediate child controls - if it is nested deeper then that, the control will not be found.

There is another overload that lets you supply how many levels of nesting the function should go through - this lets you dig deeper (at a cost - performance).

Since you can simply do `btnabout1.Visible = false;`, no need to use `FindControl` in this scenario.

Comment: This works only if are the controls automatically generated by some IDE. If you're adding controls dynamicaly (Page.Controls.Add or something similair), this solution will not work.

Comment: @user35443 - With all due respect, your answer would suffer from the same issue if you were correct. Should I downvote it too?

Comment: I just dont think that you have solutions that he needs. I think that he is not retarded and he know that he can try to use this.dačo, but if he needs use FindControl, he knows why. You can downvote it if you think that you have reason.

Comment: @user35443 - Instead of guessing, add a comment and ask the OP. I believe I understand what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

For first, I think that FindControl method is not recursive. To use this method you probably need to call it throught all parent cotrols like panel or others.

If you're using masterpage, try to use this:

```
ContentPlaceHolder h = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderName");
h.FindControl("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method as below

```
Button btnAbout=(Button)Page.FindControl("btnAbout");
btnAbout.Visible=false;
```

This is the right way to use this method.

Comment: It's not needed. Visible property is derived from Control class that is parent of Button class,

Comment: `Image btnAbout1 = (Image)Page.FindControl("btnabout1");
btnAbout1.Visible = false;` Doesn't work either. btnAbout1 is null.

Comment: told you. You need to go throught all parent controls of btnabout.